# Indexing arrays with other arrays (without using a for loop)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

Is there a way in numpy to index an array using another array. For example if I had this array:

```
a = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

and this array

```
b = [3, 1, 1, 2]
```

Would there be a way of indexing a using b such that the 0th component of the new array was the 3rd component of a, 1st component of the new array was 1st component of a and so on.

In other words end up with this

```
[4.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

I know this is easy to do with a for loop, but I explicitly want to avoid using one because I am doing this procedure with higher dimensional arrays and the result is a massive slowdown in the program.

Comment: Have you tryed `a[b]`? Because it does exactly that.

Comment: The question would be clearer if you made the assignments explicitly numpy arrays: `a = numpy.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0])`

Answer (score 3):

It's literally just `a[b]`. (Extra words because StackOverflow wants 30 characters. I would post a demo, but I can't run one from here and I don't want to fake up output.)

Comment: I tried it a few times for higher dimension arrays and ended up with more axes then I started with and assumed it had simply made an array of arrays.